# Overflow an overlaying div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an overlay which would kinda overflow the parent div. I tried the following:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <div class="home-eyecatcher" id="hijab">
                    <div class="text">  <a href="hijabs.php">Hijabs</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <div class="home-eyecatcher" id="jewellery">
                    <div class="text">  <a href="hijabs.php">Jewellery</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <div class="home-eyecatcher" id="accessories">
                    <div class="text">  <a href="hijabs.php">Accessories</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.home-eyecatcher {
    float: left;
}
#hijab, #jewellery, #accessories {
    background-size: cover;
    height: 500px;
    width: 200px;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    position: relative;
}
#hijab, #jewellery, #accessories .text {
    font-size: 60px;
    font-family:'Jura';
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
}
#hijab {
    background-image: url('../img/hijabs/home-eyecatcher 2.jpg');
}
#jewellery {
    background-image: url('../img/jewellery/home-eyecatcher 1.jpg');
    background-position: 65% 50%;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
#accessories {
    background-image: url('../img/accessories/home-eyecatcher 3.jpg');
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

But it's not happening. The parent div is shifting towards the left as I decrease the `left` of the overlay divs.

[Fiddle(widthout shift)](http://fiddle.jshell.net/K9cWk/1/show/) & [Fiddle(with shift)](http://fiddle.jshell.net/K9cWk/show/).

Why is this happening and how can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target each `.text` seperately.

Change

```
#hijab, #jewellery, #accessories .text {
    font-size: 60px;
    font-family:'Jura';
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
}
```

to

```
#hijab .text, #jewellery .text, #accessories .text {
    font-size: 60px;
    font-family: 'Jura';
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
}
```

[See here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/K9cWk/2/show/)

Comment: Couldn't believe the mistake was this small. Shame on me. :P :D Thanks btw.